# Python Selenium how to load page after two-factor authentication

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to access a site behind two-factor authentication.  I have successfully logged on to the site and the selenium webdriver loads the next page.  My problem is I can't go beyond that.  I have the URL that loads next, but when I use `get('url/beyond/logon/page')`, it bumps me back to the logon page.  How do I keep the page beyond the logon page "up" in order to scrape it?  In other words, how do I prevent it from dropping me back to the logon page?

Do I, instead of navigating to the logon page, initially navigate to the page that I try to load before it kicks me back to the logon page?  So, instead of
`get('the/logon/page')`
do I go to
`get('the/page/i/want/to/scrape')`
that way I logon and I can do what I want?

Comment: please provide the code you are using. also it would be great to have the url so it can be tested

Comment: It's my credit card providers website, so in order to replicate the problem I'm having you would need to have a valid login, etc.  I'm not going to provide that, obviously.

Comment: I figured out that I need to store the login session.  Is a cookie the best way to do that via the Options method?  So maybe
`options = Options()`
`options.add_argument("user-data-dir=path/to/cookie/file/on/my/machine")`
`driver = Firefox(firefox_options=options`)`
?

Comment: yes this is a valid option. you can safe cookies like this:
EDIT I'll post an answer so the code will be formated

Answer (score 0):

as in the comments mentioned:

safe cookies with:

```
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("path/to/cookie_file.pkl", "wb"))
```

and load them back in with:

```
cookies = pickle.load(open("path/to/cookie_file.pkl", "rb")) 
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

# refresh site
driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @shiny.  I have not experimented with the code yet as I have a couple of questions.  First (and this may be dumb), but what is `pickle`?  Next, what if the site does not use cookies to store login sessions?  I heard that some sites store a session in other ways.

Comment: not a dump question at all. you can use pickle serializing and de-serializing objects. which means, that you can store an object into a file and use it later when you need it. You shouldnt use it in any production though. When the site is storing you session some other ways you need to mimik figure out how and safe the state to re-use again later. again this could be done with pickle.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks @shiny.  I'll see what I can come up with.